# How to deserialize repeated message of one of message in C++ protobuf

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have a protobuf such as:

```
message TestWordOne {
    uint32 word = 1;
}

message TestWordTwo {
    repeated TestWordOne words = 1;
}

message TestMessage {
    oneof payload {
        TestWordTwo test_data = 1;
        <some more stuff here>
    }
}
```

Now, I can serialize in such a way:

```
TestMessage sentMessage;
TestMessage recvMessage;

    TestWordTwo* data_test(new TestWordTwo);
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
         TestWordOne* oneWord = data_test->add_words();
         oneWord->set_word(i);
    }
```

Then serialize it with outputstream

```
sentMessage.SerializeToOstream(&outputStream)
```

However, I when I

```
recvMessage.ParseFromIstream(&outputStream)
```

I have no idea on how to get words from recVMessage, one by one. Any tips?

I tried using Descriptor and Reflection, but all available examples do not specify on how to proceed in my case.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to find in *.pb.h:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
     const TestWordOne& oneWord = data_test->words(i);
     TestWordOne* oneWordMutable = data_test->mutable_words(i);
}
```

Comment: Hi, I appreciate your response. I totally forgot to include 'message TestMessage' in my question. Could you take a look at the question again and possibly help? Thank you.

Comment: @RobertM See the comment to your question. `TestMessage` is not used in the question body at all. Show your attempt, how it is used.

Comment: Yes, I've noticed. Thank you for pointing it out. Added.

Comment: Well, I just realized I do not know how to serialize the information in TestMessage as well.